# How to build and run VSCode extension Color Picker?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to learn how [Color Picker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anseki.vscode-color) extension show a custom dialog in VSCode extension. I can get the [source code](https://github.com/anseki/vscode-color) but I don't know how to build and run this extension. Can you tell me the steps to build and run this in vscode?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the same question :(
It seems it's not available in VsCode API :/

Answer (score 0):

To install and use the extension, you'll need to go to the marketplace panel, and search for the VSCode extension.

[image: Screenshot1]

When you found the extension that you want, you'll just have to click on the **install** button.

[image: Screenshot2]

To active the new extension, you'll need to reload VSCode.

Click on the reload button:

[image]

Or:

1. Open the Command Palette with this shortcut: **CTRL + Shift + P**
   Or for Mac, **CMD + Shift + P**
2. Search for **Reload Window**
3. Here you go!

Comment: Hi @Mulliganaceous,

I just created my account and I need at least 10 reputations to upload an image.

I'll try to put better screenshots, sorry.

Comment: My question is about how to build and run the extension from the source code. I installed and used the extension. Thanks for your answer but this is not the answer for my question.